# Can't add system.dll reference to dynamically compiled C#.NET code

Tags: c#, .net, windows, reference

I'm trying to dynamically compile code using CSharpCodeProvider interface to dynamically compile code at runtime for purposes of scripting my application based on this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/codecompilation.aspx article, it compiles with no problems in VS2010(only warnings about ICodeCompiler being deprecated, but I have tried both ways: ignoring the warning and leaving the code as it is, and changing code according to MSDN recommendation - neither way works), but at runtime I get a single compiler error for the dynamic code telling me that I forgot to add reference to System.dll and based on this code below I don't see how did I forget to do so:

```
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("mscorlib.dll");
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
        //cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.dll");
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Xml.dll");
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("mscorlib.dll");
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll");
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("App.exe");
```

Interestingly enough, if I repeat the line for adding the system.dll( the commented line) I get an error telling me that System.dll is double referenced. Any ideas what this is all about? Also its worth mentioning that the sample from codeproject works, while this code which is just a copy from that sample with no changes at all does not. I figured out that the sample is using .NET 2.0 along side with VC# 2005 Compiler while VS2010 uses .NET 4.0 by default so tried changing that as well but with no avail.Any help is welcome.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please could you post the exact error with message?

Answer (score 0):

remove both lines saying `cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("mscorlib.dll");`